# How to check if denominator of double number is odd?

Tags: c, double, pow

I get 2 double numbers - `basic` and  `pow` ,  and I have to calculate `basic^power` . 
My problem is that there is cases should throw error - like if the `pow` is a fraction like odd/even and the basic is a negative  - for example `basic=(-2)` and `pow=0.75=(3\4)` So it should be `(-2)^3=-8` and then `root 4 of -8` means error . so how can I detect such cases  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of `pow()`:

> pow(x, y) returns a NaN and raises the "invalid" floating-point exception for finite x < 0 and finite non-integer y.

So check for this.